# how to compressing image before upload in code igniter?

Tags: codeigniter, image-uploading

there is any trick for compressing an image in codeigniter while uploading image? so when image have 6MB memory, on the server that image just 2Mb. 
thank you for your response :D

Comment: Reduces the quality then automatically reduce the memory size

Comment: You can use image libraries to achieve that there are plenty of them on internet e.g. ImageMagick